# Создание графиков на Canvas - JS. Проблема с отрисовкой

Tags: javascript, canvas

Всем привет. Продолжаю экспериментировать с канвасом. Решил попробовать отрисовать графики, но столкнулся с небольшими изъянами графики.

Вот код (Можно нажать на W and S):

```js
"use strict"

const c = document.getElementById("ctx");

const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;

let size = 5;

function inRad(num) {
    return num * Math.PI / 180;
}


function graph() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, c.height / 2, c.width, 1);

    ctx.translate(c.width / 2, c.height / 2);
    ctx.rotate(inRad(180));

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, c.height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);

    for (let i = -2000; i < 2000; i++) {
        let x = i;
        let y = Math.floor(Math.abs(i) ^ 2) * size;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(inRad(180));
    ctx.translate(-c.width / 2, -c.height / 2);
}

graph();

window.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
    console.log(e.keyCode)
    if (e.keyCode === 119) {
        size++;
    } else if (e.keyCode === 115) {
        size--;

    }
    graph();
})
```

```html
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: Вот что интересно, если увеличить ширину лини можно детально рассмотреть узоры)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо поменять знак возведения в степень во многих языках программирования возведение в степень ^, но в js **

```
for (let i = -2000; i < 2000; i++) {
        let x = i;
        let y = Math.floor(Math.abs(i) ** 2) * size; //Заменяем ^ на **
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }
```

А ^, я сейчас посмотрела, складывает числа.

Comment: не складывает - это `xor`

Comment: Судя по всему ^ очень ненадежный оператор, раз он к 8 прибавляет 3, а из 7 тройку вычитает 

Comment: Спасибо, что поправили насчет xor, а то я тоже удивилась